# MySQLWorkbench with MariaDB 10.0 Performance tab not working

Tags: mariadb, mysql-5.6, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQLWorkbench 6.3.3.0 (build 592) and I cannot use the performance tab on a Mariadb10 connection.

This is the error I receive:

> This feature requires MySQL version 5.6.6 or newer

[image: This feature requires MySQL version 5.6.6 or newer]

The error as you can see is that workbench cannot see that MariaDB 10 has the performance schema and is assuming that the MySQL version is lower than 5.6.6 which somewhat is true as I'm not using MySQL.

I can assume that this is a compatibility issue between MySQLWorkbench and MariaDB 10?

AFAIK MariaDB is supposed to be compatible with MySQL 5.6 or am I wrong about that?

Has anyone a workaround for this?

Comment: Have you downloaded the separate schema files (forgotten where) and installed them and then tried? There's something like sys_schema... memory failing me here, but you can download significant bits separately.

Comment: Try installing the files here from [Mark Leith](https://github.com/MarkLeith/mysql-sys/) - an Oracle employee! These may help your MySQL Workbench to "see" the performance schema.

Comment: Installing MariaDB 10.0.21 installed Heidi by default and the performance schema was available through its GUI - maybe you could try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is on purpose and has nothing to do with the performance schema. MySQL Workbench is designed for MySQL and is only guaranteed (and tested) to work with MySQL servers (and checks this explicitly in certain places). And even then there are sometimes problems, caused by features not available in older versions. Let alone derivative work like MariaDB.

Comment: Pretty much this. If it checks for specific versions in the code-base, it is reasonable to see where MariaDB version would fail that check.